# Reset printer cache to force Chrome browser to select OS default printer

Tags: google-chrome, printing

Initially i changed default printer to some other, then opened the chrome in Kiosk printing when i hit ctrl+P chrome is still sending print request to previously selected default printer.

Is there any way to force the chrome to use system default printer rather from recent destination?

Comment: Contrary to the previous two remarks, I thought this was a great question - in fact, it was like the sixth or seventh item when I Googled, so I was glad it was here where I could find it. Tom's comment was also helpful so I could recognize that it's a prevalent issue so I can stop trying to find a workaround. tl;dr: thanks for your question!

Answer (score 6):

I've been looking in to this issue too.  It's unfortunate and a bit strange that Google has not been giving it much attention... I would think that it would affect a large number of users.

The best workaround I've seen after reading on it some is to use the system print dialog instead of Chrome's print dialog.  From Chrome, you can do this either by hitting Shift-Ctrl-P (in Windows), or by selecting the system print dialog at the bottom of Chrome's print dialog.

A better solution (i.e. a bug fix) would be nice, but, ...

I just sent the following bug report to the Chrome folks using the Chrome Help -> Report an Issue dialog.  (Of course it tells you not to expect any response...)

---

Print uses the last used printer as the default, instead of the system default printer.

Windows 10
Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

Normal behavior should be to always revert to the system default printer instead of the last used printer.  There are several forum threads (even on the google chrome forum!) of folks lamenting the current behavior, planning to switch to Firefox where the default printer is actually the default printer.  Interesting threads:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=431098 (merged into the following issue)

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=254428 (last user marked this as resolved but it actually persists)

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=454258 (not sure what the outcome is here; it has been idle for almost a year)

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/qCFCE3xi7SA (see the next to last entry from Terry@LanZone, 11/19/12)

Answer (score 2):

In current versions of Chrome, it is possible to use a GPO or pass the command line argument `--use-system-default-printer` to have it always use the default printer. You can also edit the Preferences file or use a Master Preferences file with `printing.print_preview_sticky_settings` set to empty.

Comment: Yess, that's it... Actually, what I did was simple delete this key/value (printing.print_preview_sticky_settings) inside ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences . I'm using Linux Mint.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by performing the following steps. 
1. Update Chrome by clicking the 3 dots in the upper right, go to about chrome, then update. Version 60 you click the 3 dots, click settings, click about chrome, update.
2. After chrome was updated i went into my printers in windows and switched my default printer to another device and then set it back to the one I wanted. Then I opened chrome, printed a page to the default printer, then closed chrome. When I reopened chrome my default was listed first.

Comment: I have Version 60.0.3112.90 (Official Build) (32-bit) and it still doesn't use the default printer.